# getBoundingClientRect() is returning 0 values

Tags: javascript, getboundingclientrect

When using the Muuri library inside a bootstrap tab, it doesn't place the items in the correct position. All this is caused because Muuri is using getBoundingClientRect() to get the size of the main container and this function is returning 0 values for some reason. I will appreciate your help.

```js
var grid = new Muuri('.grid');
```

```css
.item{
    position:absolute;
    background: green;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    top: 50px !important;
    left: 50px !important;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/muuri@0.9.3/dist/muuri.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="bd-example bd-example-tabs">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home"
                    aria-selected="true">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab"
                    aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab"
                    aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                <p>Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua,
                    retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica.
                    Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth. Cosby sweater eu banh mi, qui irure terry
                    richardson ex squid. Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american
                    apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
                <div class="grid">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="item-content">
                            Box 1
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="item-content">
                            Box 2
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
                <p>Etsy mixtape wayfarers, ethical wes anderson tofu before they sold out mcsweeney's organic lomo retro
                    fanny pack lo-fi farm-to-table readymade. Messenger bag gentrify pitchfork tattooed craft beer,
                    iphone skateboard locavore carles etsy salvia banksy hoodie helvetica. DIY synth PBR banksy irony.
                    Leggings gentrify squid 8-bit cred pitchfork. Williamsburg banh mi whatever gluten-free, carles
                    pitchfork biodiesel fixie etsy retro mlkshk vice blog. Scenester cred you probably haven't heard of
                    them, vinyl craft beer blog stumptown. Pitchfork sustainable tofu synth chambray yr.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Done, you can see tab Profile having Box 1 over Box 2 instead of beside.

Comment: Both boxes are set with the same `top` value, with `!important` so they are more difficult to override.

Comment: Please, always include such important details + do so in the question. Also it is better to create a MINIMAL example that shows the problem *at first glance*, instead of us having to take a non-obvious action to see the issue.

Comment: .item is set to absolute, so grid has no content to expand it.

Comment: @HereticMonkey If I remove this, nothing else than the boxes being a little closer to the top but still one over the other one.

Comment: @CharlesBamford If I remove absolute, the items won't render inline.

Comment: @DanielRios I'm letting you know why the bounding box is 0 x 0, not telling you how to fix your page. In most cases there are better ways to arrange elements than position: absolute.

Comment: @CharlesBamford more than happy to hear the betters ways, that probably fix the issue, thanks for your help.